# How to create table with column names that look like HSQLDB keywords?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

The following SQL will not accepted by HSQLDB because of the name 'position' is a keyword.

CREATE MEMORY TABLE bb (position bigint)

How to create this table without changing the column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know HSQLDB, but some SQLs let you use special quotes to force them to accept reserved identifiers.

I'd suggest trying first single quotes, then backticks. If that doesn't work, someone else will hopefully have posted something that does! :)

Comment: In case I didn't make that clear, I meant to try quoting 'position' and ``position`` .

Comment: oh, I have tried several quotes.  CREATE MEMORY TABLE bb ("position" bigint) works.  Thanks

Answer (score 11):

From the [HSQLDB User Guide](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html):

> All keywords, can be used for database
>   objects if they are double quoted.

So your statement should simply read:

```
CREATE MEMORY TABLE bb ("position" bigint)
```

Comment: +1: Superior knowledge to the rescue. Sorry for grabbing that from ya!

Comment: Not at all - I actually felt bad answering because it was really superior googling to the rescue. Glad you got the green tick.